# show effect with mouseover and hide effect when mouseout, HOW?

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseout

so my problem here it's that the effect activate by the mouseover stay after the mouseout... anyone can show me how transform the js to make disapear the effect when the mouse out of the menu ?

Thank you

```js
<script>
  (function() {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu')).forEach(function(menu) {
      var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu__link'),
      setCurrent = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

                  var item = ev.target.parentNode; // li

                  // return if already current
                  if (classie.has(item, 'menu__item--current')) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  // remove current
                  classie.remove(menu.querySelector('.menu__item--current'), 'menu__item--current');
                  // set current
                  classie.add(item, 'menu__item--current');
                };

                [].slice.call(menuItems).forEach(function(el) {
                  el.addEventListener('mouseover', setCurrent);
                });
              });

    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.link-copy')).forEach(function(link) {
      link.setAttribute('data-clipboard-text', location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '#' + link.parentNode.id);
      new Clipboard(link);
      link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        classie.add(link, 'link-copy--animate');
        setTimeout(function() {
          classie.remove(link, 'link-copy--animate');
        }, 300);
      });
    });
  })(window);
  </script>
```

```html
  <section class="section section--menu" id="maria">
        <nav class="menu menu--maria">
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down menu__list">
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Illustration</a>
            </li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Edition</a></li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Graphisme</a></li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
```

Comment: are you trying to show the whole list when the mouse is over it and hide the whole list when the mouse is out of the list?...describe exactly what you want to happen..:D

Comment: @repzero i want the effect active when i hover a link and inactive when the mouse is out of menu links, for now if i hover for example the link "illustration" and if i put the mouse out of any links the effect stay on "illustration"  even if i mouse out...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you'd like something like this.

Take out the border  if needed (This is just an approach)

**snippet below**

```js
all_li=document.getElementsByClassName('indigo-text menu__item');
function mouseover(el){
all_li[el].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.children[0].classList.remove('disable');
 this.children[0].classList.add('enable');

}
,false)
all_li[el].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.children[0].classList.remove('enable');
 this.children[0].classList.add('disable');

}
,false)
} //end of function
for(i=0;i<all_li.length;++i){
mouseover(i)

}
```

```css
a {
 pointer-events:none; 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:grey;
}
.disable {
 pointer-events:none; 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:grey;
}
.enable {
 pointer-events:auto; 
 text-decoration: underline;
 color:black;
}
ul{
  border:solid;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="section section--menu" id="maria">
        <nav class="menu menu--maria">
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down menu__list">
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Illustration</a>
            </li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Edition</a></li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Graphisme</a></li>
            <li class="indigo-text menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
```